# online database containing seforim information

Tags: jewish-books, internet, publications

does anyone know of an online database that has seforim information, including author, year of publication, and short description.
Thanks in advance

Comment: HebrewBooks and the Israeli National Library are pretty good

Comment: thanks, is this data that i can query / download?